# after fresh installation of nutch and solr crawl error

Tags: solr, nutch

I have a problem after fresh installation of nutch 1.19 and solr 8.11.2. After running the crawl process, crawling finishes with an NullPointerException and the following Error message:

Error running:
/opt/solr/apache-nutch-1.19/bin/nutch fetch -Dsolr.server.url=http//localhost:8983/solr/nutch -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=2 -Dmapreduce.reduce.speculative=false -Dmapreduce.map.speculative=false -Dmapreduce.map.output.compress=true -D fetcher.timelimit.mins=180 crawl/segments/20230106121647 -threads 50
Failed with exit value 255.

Has anybody an idea what causes this error?

Comment: It's difficult to say what causes the error without the stack trace of the NullPointerException or some context from the crawler log (stdout or hadoop.log).

Comment: here are the latest log entries in hadoop.log:

Comment: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.3.4.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.3.4.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
...

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the memory (Java heap) is not sufficient to spin up 50 fetcher threads. You could try the following:

1. if you do not need the default number of 50 fetcher threads, reduce it by passing the option `--num-threads n_threads` to bin/crawl
2. the Java heap size can be set via the environment variable `NUTCH_HEAPSIZE` - the default is 4 MB which should be sufficient even with 50 threads unless you have very large documents (eg. PDF files) to parse and index.
3. there might be limits on your system which require to use less memory or threads